# TextView layout_gravity not working programmatically

Tags: android, layout, textview

I've been looking around and have found many possible solutions for centering a textview in a layout. But none worked for me.
My textview is in a TableLayout which is described by the following xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/schedule_main_holder">
    <TableLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:stretchColumns="0"
      android:id="@+id/schedule_table_entry">
   </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm doing is making a new TableRow and then adding a TextView and a ListView to it...but the textview has to be centered vertically. For that I'm doing:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TextView tview = new TextView(this);
        tview.setText("Wednesday");
        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        tview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        row.addView(tview);
```

The problem is that the TextView is always on top of the cell and not in the middle as it should.
I've tried a mix of combinations (even the FrameLayout method describe in another response) and I can't get the textview to be centered in the table cell.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there are two types of gravity.I think your using regular gravity not the layout one.
second you could also create the view in xml then use inflatrer and then add. This gives much cleaner code aswel.

Edit:
So your too lazy to ACTUALLY try layout inflater and listen to advice, here is the code:

main.xml

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchColumns="0"
android:id="@+id/schedule_table_entry">
</TableLayout>
```

myrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</TableRow>
```

TestActivity

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myrow, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("I did all your work... smart even");

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.schedule_table_entry);
    table.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have already tried the inflater method and the layout_gravity was simple ignored. I do want the layout_gravity because I want the textview to be centered on the cell not the text itself. At least I've tried setGravity and it didn't work and when the textview was defined in xml the layout_gravity worked.

Comment: Updated response to do the suggestion.. suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I just tried and it works. I did try the inflate approach but not in the a TableRow, instead I inflated the TextView directly and that might have been the issue.

Comment: Well to be honest I've been through my own querrels with gravity ;)